# When are the bounded continuous functions dense in a topological probability space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $(\mathcal{X},\tau)$ is a topological space, $\mathcal{F}$ is its Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu :\mathcal{F} \to [0,1]$ is a probability measure.

If one of the following two conditions holds:

- $(\mathcal{X},\tau)$ is [locally compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) and [Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space);
- $(\mathcal{X},\tau)$ is [Polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space);

then the bounded continuous functions are dense in $L^1(\mu)$ (as a corollary of Lusin's theorem that holds in both settings).

Is this result true in general? If not, are there natural topological conditions (say, a characterization or something that comes close to it) under which this result holds true?